# Grid only displaying one Column

Tags: grid, react-virtualized

I've recently started trying to use react-virtualized, but I've ran into an issue from the get-go. I've been trying to build a very simple grid, at first I loaded my data in and it wasn't working properly, but I've changed it to a simple 4x4 Grid and it's still giving me issues. Right now all 16 cells are being loading in a single column, and I've tried logging the rowIndex and the columnIndex, and those are giving me the correct output.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong when I call the Grid, or if I'm doing something wrong with the cellRenderer, I would really appreciate some help with this. I have parts of my code down below.

```
_cellRenderer({columnIndex, key, rowIndex, styles}){
    return(
        <div> 
            {columnIndex} 
        </div>);
}

render(){
    return(
    <div>
        <Autosizer>
            {({width}) => (
                <Grid
                    cellRenderer={this._cellRenderer}
                    columnCount={4}
                    columnWidth={30}
                    rowCount={4}
                    rowHeight={30}
                    width={400}
                    height={400}
                />
             )}
        </Autosizer>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the parameters passed to your renderer. For example, `style` and `key` are both passed for a reason and you *must use them*. (The documentation should make this pretty clear.)

Put another way:

```
// Wrong:
function cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {columnIndex}
    </div>
  )
}
​
// Right:
function cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
  return (
    <div
      key={key}
      style={style}
    >
      {columnIndex}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Also, in case you didn't notice, the parameter is `style` and not `styles` like your code snippet shows.

Comment: Thanks for responding, sorry for the typo - I'm using stack overflow on a different machine so there were a few typos - I've tried doing that and it still doesn't seem to work properly, I did what you suggested for the cellRenderer but it doesn't seem to work. I'm currently using a 4x4 array, and when I try printing out the columnIndex it just gives me everything in a single line. I've tried editing it according to the examples, and reduced the complexity and size of the input everytime, and tried looking through the documentation and other posts on both github and stack-overflow as well.

Comment: Clean up your question. I answered the only interpretation of it I could come up with, based on the limited information you provided and the obvious bug in it. Stack Overflow questions like this need links to CodeSandbox or Plunker examples for this very reason.

Comment: Sorry about the trouble, I made a CodeSandbox with my example,https://codesandbox.io/s/2o5n1v2z5p

Comment: My original answer pointed out the problem. You're using `styles` instead of `style`....

Comment: ... I see, I'm sorry for the trouble, thank you so much for all of your help!